# Install and run - OpenGL ES 3.0 on Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk, release, development-environment

I just read about the release of OGLES 3.

Some has any idea if it is already feasible to install it on Android Smartphones and use it for developing 3D Apps? Or this will be possible only by 2013?

Here is an article about it:
http://www.khronos.org/news/press/khronos-releases-opengl-es-3.0-specification

All comments are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check in the [Google Android Source Code](http://source.android.com/) for the version of the open GL. If you are in the process of building a custom ROM for your custom hardware and deploying your app as a System app (ROM app) then it is possible.

Comment: Unlikely. First would need the OpenGL ES 3.0 API bindings in the Android framework (do able but a lot of work) and also drivers that support the hardware (of course you need to have 3.0 supporting hardware which only a limited number of devices do). The drivers are unlikely, most embedded gpus have closed source binary blobs and Android uses a different graphics stack to other devices.

Answer (score 4):

Supposing that you want an hardware accelerated context for OpenGL, If the targeted hardware do not support a particular version of OpenGL you can't simply update it to the next version, because of the driver and because of the hardware.